# File Read Write using Ant Script

Tags: ant

I have 2 files:

Read.txt:

> My name is=Joy
>
> My age is=18

Write.txt:

> Paste my name here:
>
> Paste my age here:

So I should be able to read the name(Joy) and age(18) from Read.txt from the desired location(it will appear after '=') and write them into write.txt at the desired location(after ':') after a successful build. Do I need regex for this?

Can we do this using an Ant Script?

Comment: Ant is a build tool, it's not normally used for processing data in this way.  FWIW: you don't need regex, and you can do it using Ant.

Comment: Ant uses Java style properties, so the property names can't contain whitespace characters. It's still possible to do what you're trying to accomplish but it would be much easier if the words were separated by a non-whitespace character such as `_` or `-`.

Answer (score 1):

With invalid property names in your read.txt file, you'll have to do something a bit more complex.

Using the `loadfile` task, you can load the entire contents of the file and format it as necessary:

```
<target name="write-to-file">
    <loadfile srcfile="read.txt" property="output">
        <filterchain>
            <tokenfilter>
                <replacestring from="My name is=" to="Paste my name here:" />
                <replacestring from="My age is=" to="Paste my age here:" />
            </tokenfilter>
        </filterchain>
    </loadfile>

    <echo file="write.txt" message="${output}" />
</target>
```

If you need to get the specific values for name and age (perhaps for use later in the script) you will have to load twice and filter the parts you need:

```
<target name="load-lines">
    <loadfile srcfile="read.txt" property="my.name">
        <filterchain>
            <linecontains>
                <contains value="My name is" />
            </linecontains>
            <tokenfilter>
                <replacestring from="My name is=" to="" />
            </tokenfilter>
        </filterchain>
    </loadfile>

    <loadfile srcfile="read.txt" property="my.age">
        <filterchain>
            <linecontains>
                <contains value="My age is" />
            </linecontains>
            <tokenfilter>
                <replacestring from="My age is=" to="" />
            </tokenfilter>
        </filterchain>
    </loadfile>

    <echo file="write.txt" message="Paste my name here:${my.name}${line.separator}Paste my age here:${my.age}" />
</target>
```